# Debugging CMake based application in Netbeans

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake, netbeans-6.9

I have converted a CMake based application to Netbeans project on Ubuntu. The problem is that, although I can run the application, I am unable to debug the code (something for which I did the whole thing). I have tried to reset the "Console Type" and "Terminal Type" properties in Properties->Run tab. Although it works for projects built "with Netbeans" but apparently its not working for CMake based applications.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks
Ikram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set the build type in CMake to be Debug?

Comment: In fact the long cmake script was written by someone else and now after adding build type info in there, its working now :)